# Alice predicts the USD to EUR exchange rate to increase $10\%$ in one year. Bob predicts the same for the EUR to USD rate. Can they both be right?

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle

Here is a brainteaser from Michael Isichenko`s "Quantitative Portfolio Management: The Art and Science of Statistical Arbitrage".

> Alice's model predicts the USD to EUR exchange rate to increase $10\%$ in one year. Bob's forecast indicates the same increase for EUR to USD rate over the same period. Can Alice and Bob both be right?

Can anybody help with the solution? I guess the answer should be "yes", but I do not really understand why.

Comment: This is a trick finances answer. I guess off topic from here. Perhaps in a finance forum you could get an answer, not in here.

Comment: @Brethlosze I do not think this really has anything to do with finance. Actually the question could be reformulated as give example of random variable x which has E(x)>1 and E(1/x)>1. For example 1.1 with p=0.6 and 0.86 with p=0.4 would work.

Comment: I mean, this question holds specific finance concept, deeper than the sole x vs 1/x comparison, which would allow this apparent paradox to be solved, which I am afraid in this maths forum would not be properly tackled

Comment: What about https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would be keen to know the answer as well... perhaps the answer is just "No" and meant to confuse.

Comment: @Gleb is right. A more general lognormal variable will work too. The only 'financial' or 'trick' thing here is that prediction is usually understood as expectation.  Thanks for your interest in this riddle.